# Getting 401 for endpoint with permitAll permission

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Getting 401 for "/register" endpoint even after defining it as permitAll in antMatcher.

I am new to spring security.
I have configured two endpoints "/login" and "/register". I want "/register" to be available public and there should be a username/password check on accessing "/login".

My server.servlet.context-path is set to "/todo/user".

I tried to search for the solution but nothing would explain why i am facing the issue or may be i wasnt able to comprehend it being new to this.

Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> registration(@RequestBody @Valid UserRegistration userRegistration) {

        Optional<UserRegistration> user = Optional.ofNullable(userRegistration);
        if(!user.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserDataNotAvailableException("User data is not available");
        }
        //TO-DO Write implementation of isUserValid
        Optional<Boolean> isRegistrationSuccess = user.map(userService::registerNewUser);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("This is temp", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilter(new 
JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Authentication Filter

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private static final int EXPIRATION_TIME = 3900;

    private static final String HEADER_NAME = "auth";

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        try{
            UserLogin user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UserLogin.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmailId(), user.getPassword(),
                    new ArrayList<>()));
        }catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InternalServerException("There was a problem in processing the request");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String jwt = Jwts.builder().setSubject(((UserLogin)authResult.getPrincipal()).getEmailId())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()  + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, secret)
                .compact();
        response.addHeader(HEADER_NAME, jwt);

    }
}
```

AS evident from security config class i have permitted all to access my "/register" endpoint.

But when i make a request on "/register" i get a 401.
This should not be the case and i should be able to access this particular endpoint without any JWT

Comment: Do you try to delete this value in `@RequestMapping` in endpoint, maybe this is the problem in matcher

Comment: @Sebastian I tried removing it but didn't worked

Comment: What if you delete HttpMerhod.POST from configuration, basically there is no need to define HttpMethods. I just try to shoot what is wrong because i dont see problem :/

Comment: try changing the annotation of your Controller class to `@RestController` and have you confirmed that your endpoint works without spring security?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Yes i have confirmed my code works absolutely fine without spring security. Only after adding spring security i started facing the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a 401 status code? I would expect a 403 if you don't include a CSRF token.